# Trouble when open image with PILLOW in python

Tags: file-io, python-imaging-library

I am using pillow to open image in python (2.7.4 - 64 bit windows 7)
Link to download Pillow at here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (Pillow-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe)

But After install it, I always get error when open image. Example:

```
import Image
import cStringIO

temp_file = open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\images.png', 'rb+')
content = cStringIO.StringIO(temp_file.read())
image = Image.open(content)
```

I got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    image = Image.open(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2008, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do this:

```
from PIL import Image
image=Image.open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\images.png')
```

I don't see why you would use cStringIO for this example.  Note the difference for the import line as well.

Comment: At the beginning, I use like the way you did, but It error. So I try with cStringIO. But I got same result.

Comment: Well, that demonstrates that your problem has nothing to do with cStringIO.  You should edit the question to reflect that (i.e. remove code related to cStringIO).  Have you tried changing the way you import the library?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case I had not uninstalled PIL before installing PILLOW.
Once I uninstalled PIL, then uninstalled PILLOW, then reinstalled PILLOW, everything worked.